# Reconnect to ASP.NET Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have an ASP.NET page that gathers some user information, then sends a post including a url to a third-party web site for processing. After processing the third party web site sends a post back to the url included in the original post. The problem is when the new page receives the post message the `SessionID` is different and the user information is not in the new session. If I store the original `SessionID` can I use it to connect to the original session?

Comment: Why don't you send the POST from the user page and let the user wait for it by simply showing a loading image... or, delegate the POST to other action that at the end, you will update the database and for such, allow the user to know that was posted? - First part with `$.post()` and the second with a bit more code.

Comment: Its wrong to use the session as we use a database. Session can be easily lost for any reason, is expired, the cookie is different, the pool restarts on memory sessions, etc. Even if you solve it, you may still have issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran into situations like this before, I used a few different solutions.

- One approach is similar to Nico's where the site asked for a URI to post back to, and I attached a guid which pointed to a temporary table in the database (I don't like putting the UserID in the URL just like that). My version was:

  http://www.mysite.com/myThirdPartyCallBack?guid=abcd12345-fgsdfg-3rqwer

Then, you can get the value(s) back from the database that you put in there before third-party redirect.

- Second approach is to write needed data into cache before redirect. Since you can set the life of the data to be short, this can be a neat solution and you do not expose any information via URL. Just be careful to identify the user if necessary.

Comment: I only need the user object in the other page for a few seconds, so the cache seems to be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is no. You cannot reuse an existing session. The purpose of the session is to be unique to each visitor across multiple platforms (and browsers).

If I understand correctly the third party site is post asyncronously back to the URL specified. If this is the case then the third part request is being assigned a new session ID as it is a new session to your web application. I would suggest modifying your call back URL to post back some information that then allows you to locate the user information that was originally sent over. This can be done by just providing a querystring key that denotes the user ID, or more advanced point to a key in your web storage system to locate more details on the original request. Such as `http://www.mysite.com/myThirdPartyCallBack?userID=abcd12345`

On the other hand, if the following processes is happening. User posts a form to a third party site. Then the user completes some work on the third party site and is then redirected back to your site then this is more of a session timing issue. If this is the case then I would inspect your session timings to ensure they are long enough for user to complete the work on the third party site.

Just and idea.

Comment: You first assumption is correct. It is done this way so the sensitive user entered data does not actually touch my site.

Comment: @jac I figured so, your best bet is to include some sort of cryptic query string parameter in your callback. In these cases I have used a hashed string that contains user info that must be decoded using a custom salted hash provider.